# Mage_Ship_Helper_Data not found

Tags: magento-1.9

Been scratching my head over this problem for a while now, have tried adding the helper to the config etc. Updating from 1.7 (where there were no problems) and now getting this error in the config: `'Mage_Ship_Helper_Data' not found`

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Ship>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Excellence_Ship>
    </modules>

    <default>
        <carriers>
            <excellence>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>ship/carrier_excellence</model>
                <title>Carrier Title</title>
                <name>Method Name</name>
                <price>5.00</price>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </excellence>
        </carriers>
    </default>

    <blocks>
        <ship>
            <class>Excellence_Ship_Block</class>
        </ship>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart_shipping>Excellence_Ship_Block_Cart_Shipping</cart_shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>         
    </blocks>

    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <dummy_products>
                                            <title>Configure Dummy Products</title>
                                        </dummy_products>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next to the `blocks` node, which should be wrapped in a `global` node,  also add

```
<models>
    <ship>
        <class>Excellence_Ship_Model</class>
    </ship>       
</models>
<helpers>
    <ship>
        <class>Excellence_Ship_Helper</class>
    </ship>       
</helpers>
```

Magento needs this to convert `Mage::helper('ship')->someFunction()` to the actual `Excellence_Ship_Helper_Data::someFunction()`. Same goes for models.

Using `Mage` is a last resort fallback which indeed would fail since the class doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks bud, added it after the blocks node, but still getting same error :(

Comment: Clear your config cache as well

Comment: caching is disabled

Comment: and Helper/Data.php just contains the blank class `class Excellence_Ship_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data` which afaik is correct

Comment: both answers were correct putting it in <global> fixed

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Your `config.xml` is invalid. The `blocks` node is supposed to be a child of a `global` node. This is also the place for the `helpers` definition. Make yourself comfortable with `config.xml` structure at [Magento module configuration file reference](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/08/31/magento-module-configuration-file-reference.html).